# How should I validate fields_for in habtm relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models: Document and Keyword. They are habtm in relation to each other.

In my new document form, I do this:

```
<%= form_for @document, url: admin_add_doc_path, :html => {:multipart => true } do |f| %>
<%=  f.fields_for @keywords do |words| %>
```

In the model I have this:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
validates_associated :keywords
```

and:

```
class Keyword < ApplicationRecord
validates :keyword, presence: true
```

And in the document_controller I have:

```
def create
  @document = Document.new(document_params)
  @keywords = Keyword.new

  if @document.save
    @last_doc = Document.last
    a.each { |var| @document.keywords << Keyword.find(var)  } #a = each keyword
    redirect_to see_doc_url(@last_doc)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

This code validates the form even when no keywords are present. How should I run this through validation and send it back to form if no keywords are entered?

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing `Keyword` object like this,

```
@keywords = @document.keywords.new
```

Also, in `Document` model, add this

```
has_many :keywords
validates :keywords, presence: true
```

Hope that helps!